# Magento Order email template

Tags: orders, invoice, ce-1.9.0.1, email-templates

I have terribly looking templates for customers' emails with new order and new invoice.
In order confirmation I don't even have list of bought items and prices. Is here any good template for it, I have found nothing.

Thank you very much.

BTW I use built in magento templates.

Comment: what u mean by  "I don't even have list of bought items and prices"?

Comment: When customer gets email an email with order confirmation, it includes text with what I wrote there and customers shipping and billing information but there is nothing written about products his bought, subtotal, grandtotal, shipping cost, nothing.. And I can't find any variables which contains this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the default templates in the `app/locale/en_US/template/email/` directory. The default New Order is in `sales/order_new.html` and the default New Invoice is `sales/invoice_new.html`. There are variables in these template files but this should help you with editing the basic template of the email.